# how to trigger webhook from zapier code

Tags: javascript, integration, webhooks, fetch-api, zapier

I have 2 zaps. First finishes with `Code by Zapier` block, where I parse input information from previous steps getting array with data e.g.:

```
var elements = [{id: 12, calculatedValue: 13},{id: 13, calculatedValue: 'red'}]
```

then in a loop I traverse it, create requests bodies

```
var options = {
      "url": "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/",
      "method": "POST"
    },
    requests = elements.map(mapDataToSettings);

function mapDataToSettings(elem) {
  var settings = Object.assign({}, options);
  settings.data = JSON.stringify(elem);
  return settings;
};
```

Then I'm doing HTTP calls with `Fetch API` for all those requests:

```
Promise.all(requests.map(grabContent))
.then(function(data){ callback(null, {requestsMade: data});});

function grabContent(options) {
  return fetch(options.url, options)
     .then(function(res) {return res.json();});
};
```

**N.B.** `callback` is function of Zapier to handle async results.

This code successfully runs and I can see results:

[image]

But those requests are not registered in webhook (address is correct. double checked.)

**What may be the reason for this? How to fix my code to make requests activate webhook?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you don't have a `body` item in your `options` that get sent with the `fetch` method. [The documentation](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/tree/32b60634434a63865ea3f79edb33d17e40876c9f#usage) shows this as a `POST` example: `{ method: 'POST', body: 'a=1' }`, so maybe try to make it exactly like that.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I've seen somewhere that fetch information object had `data` property, thus made this typo.