# Zapier code: trigger multiple webhooks

Tags: javascript, webhooks, zapier

I'm trying to send multiple webhooks based on the number of items in a JSON array. I'm using a example from:
[how to trigger webhook from zapier code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002614/how-to-trigger-webhook-from-zapier-code/51010668#51010668)

I tried it and it almost works as planned. I have a problem that when I have a JSON array of 4 items, it sends 16 webhooks instead of 4. If I have A JSON array of 3 items, it sends out 9 webhooks instead of 3.

I use inputData.items for insertion of the JSON array. Does anyone know why the items in the JSON array are multiplied?

I used:

```
const elements = JSON.parse(inputData.items)
var body = elements;
var options = {
  "url": "URL.COM",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  "body": JSON.stringify(body)
},
requests = elements.map(mapDataToSettings);

function mapDataToSettings(elem) {
  var settings = Object.assign({}, options);
  settings.data = JSON.stringify(elem);
  return settings;
};

Promise.all(requests.map(grabContent))
.then(function(data){ callback(null, {requestsMade: data});});

function grabContent(options) {
  return fetch(options.url, options)
     .then(function(res) {return res.json();});
};
```

Does anyone see why my webhooks are triggering to often?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

It's hard to say for sure without seeing your zap, but my guess is that you're feeding `.items` in from a previous Code step where it's returned as an array? If so, you're running into an undocumented code feature where subsequent steps are run for each item in the array. This is usually desirable, but since you're doing a loop in the code, you don't need it.

Assuming that's the case, you've got two options:

1. Return a sjon string from the previous step (instead of an array) so this code step only runs once.
2. Change this code to only receive one item and perform a request with it.

If something else is going on, update your question with the zap id (it's not sensitive info) and I can take a look!

Comment: Hi David, thanks for reaching out. Zap ID = 35806039 (step 10).

Comment: I took a look and nothing jumps out - doesn't look like there are any arrays. I'm not sure what the webhook does, but I did notice each that the body of each webhook is all the items. Maybe that's the source of the repetition? if the input is `[1,2,3]`, then 9 items get sent to that webhook url. Past that, I'm not sure

Comment: Okay, thanks. So if i'm correct it's not necessary to loop the code. At first I wanted to loop the code so we could send a webhook for every json item, but apparently the receiving end already handles every item as a seperate request. Do you know how to delete the loop from this request?

Comment: Not needed anymore. If I send the JSON array containing 4 items, the receiving webhook already picks it up as 4 different requests instead of 1 request with an array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).